тг бот не реагирует на команду и не отправляет сообщение
по задумке бот должен отправить сообщение х пользователю 1, когда получает команду y от пользователя 2
from telebot import TeleBot as Tb
API_TOKEN = "some_token"
bot = Tb(API_TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['y'])
def command_y(message):
    if message.chat.id == user_id_2:
        bot.send_message(user_id_1, x_message)

bot.infinity_polling(allowed_updates=['message'])

при получении команды, бот на нее ни как не реагирует, и я не могу понять почему
тестил бота, заменяя user_id_1 и user_id_2 на собственный id

для тех кто наткнется в будущем: я решил проблему. В вопросе я указал только часть кода, но по факту, хендлер команды у меня был указан после хендлера обычных сообщений, и из-за этого просто игнорился компилятором. Указывайте хендлеры комманд до обычных хендлеров :)

Очередность не зависит от того, хендлер этот с командой или, как вы выразились, "обычный". Все хендлеры проверяются в том порядке, в котором они расположены. Сработает первый, который подойдет и дальнейшая проверка хендлеров прекращается
